# SQL JOIN problem in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT bw.Bor_name
FROM Borrower AS bw, Loan AS l
JOIN Book_Copy AS bc
ON l.Bc_id = bc.Bc_id
WHERE bw.Bor_id = l.Bor_id
GROUP BY l.Bor_id, bc.Bt_id
HAVING COUNT( bc.Bt_id ) > 1
AND COUNT( l.Bor_id ) > 1;
```

This works perfectly in a MySQL testing environment but won't work in MS Access 2007 where I actually need it run. I have a few other queries which involve using JOIN and it gives the same error for them as well: "Syntax error in FROM clause".

Edit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.Bor_id
FROM Loan AS l
INNER JOIN Book_Copy AS bc
ON l.Bc_id = bc.Bc_id
GROUP BY l.Bor_id, bc.Bt_id
HAVING COUNT( bc.Bt_id ) > 1
AND COUNT( l.Bor_id ) > 1
```

Actually this one works fine and gives me the required id number, but what I want to output is the name which is contained in the Borrower table.

Comment: Are you really using MySQL to prototype for MS Access?  Just curious.

Comment: This isn't the source of your problem (the JOIN without INNER/LEFT/RIGHT is the problem), but why did you do one of your joins explicitly, l=>bc, and one implicitly, bw=>l? Both are INNER JOINs, so there should be any problem doing both with a JOIN. While Jet usually optimizes equivalent implicit and explicit JOINs identically, I would want this to be an explicit JOIN -- I never use implicit JOINs except when there's a good reason to do so.

Comment: @Larry: MySQL is what I have as a testing environment at home. Unfortunately, I don't have Access 2007 to test right now, and my response to what actually helped will be posted no sooner than Monday.

Comment: @David: Thank you very much for the reply! I really believe you are competent enough and I appreciate your concern very much. Yes, at first I tried with LEFT/RIGHT joins but it would give me the same error. I'll play more with it when I am able to test in Access again.

Comment: Er, thanks? That is, for confirming my competence?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, I had read some other replies (of yours which were solving those particular cases) on similar problems here but I coudln't find the answer I needed among them. I feel kind of bad I am not seeing it and bothering people with it again.

Comment: Bothering people! Keep asking until you get a solution! I find that most often my own questions aren't answerable, because by the time I get to asking them on SO, I've already exhausted all the obvious solutions, and so I then have to keep poking at people's responses to try to figure out if they are suggesting something that will work. So, don't give up...

Comment: Thanks very much for the support once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT bw.Bor_name
FROM Borrower AS bw, Loan AS l
JOIN Book_Copy AS bc
ON (l.Bc_id = bc.Bc_id)
WHERE bw.Bor_id = l.Bor_id
GROUP BY bw.Bor_name, bc.Bt_id
HAVING COUNT( bc.Bt_id ) > 1
AND COUNT( l.Bor_id ) > 1;
```

Eventually this one did the job. Thanks once again to all who contributed with advice!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test with Access 2007.  However Access 2003 complains about "syntax error in from clause" if I try JOIN alone (without explicitly using INNER JOIN).  Seems the database engine requires you designate the JOIN as either RIGHT JOIN, LEFT JOIN, or INNER JOIN; I can't find any other variation it will accept.

Update: I will suggest you create a new query with Access' query designer.  Just add the tables and set up the joins.  (Leave the GROUP BY and everything else for later.)  Then you can switch to SQL View to see the type of join syntax which makes Access happy.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response here too! Yes, that's what I have tried so far, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot mix implicit and explicit join. you should  try with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT bw.Bor_name
FROM Borrower AS bw
join Loan AS l
on bw.Bor_id = l.Bor_id
JOIN Book_Copy AS bc
ON l.Bc_id = bc.Bc_id
GROUP BY l.Bor_id, bc.Bt_id
HAVING COUNT( bc.Bt_id ) > 1
AND COUNT( l.Bor_id ) > 1;
```

Comment: You can mix implicit/explicit JOINs in Jet/ACE/Access SQL. The problem is hte lack of JOIN type, INNER/LEFT/RIGHT.

Comment: just to confirm - it works perfectly in MySQL. I'll test again in Access and let you know what the result was.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem mixing implicit and explicit JOINs in Access, either, as long as the proper JOIN syntax is used.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code suggested above does not work in MS Access either. It still gives me the same annoying error.

Comment: Unsing INNER/LEFT/RIGHT does not help either.